# Why typeof 1/0 is NaN?

Tags: javascript

Chrome console on typing **typeof 1/0** gives **NaN**

But it is not true, because 1/0 is Infinity, which is not NaN.

How is it possible?

Comment: infinity is not a number ?

Comment: But "typeof Infinity" works well, giving "number"

Comment: `1/0` is undefined. Not infinity.

Comment: 0/0 is undefined. 1/0 is in fact infinity.

Comment: I see, so it is actually "typeof undefined", thanks!

Comment: Incidentally `NaN` is also of type 'number'

Comment: 1/0 is `Infinity` in Chrome console

Comment: @setec **No**, `typeof undefined` is `undefined`. NaN is **not** undefined.

Comment: 1/0 is Infinity, but Infinity is not a number, even if it's type is "number", just like isNaN("3") works even if it's a string.

Comment: Oh I see in IEEE 754 it is defined as "Infinity".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because the `typeof` operator [has more precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) than `/`. Your code is equivalent to:

```
(typeof 1) / 0
```

Which is `NaN`.

Issuing:

```
typeof (1 / 0)
```

Gives the expected result, `"number"`.

Answer (score 4):

Try `typeof (1/0)`, it gets the desired result.